# Flow - Defining interface based on props for a react component

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

With Flow, I want to be able to specify an interface for a functional react component that defines a few methods that the component takes as properties.

I want a wrapper component to be able to set those properties on the child component that implements those properties.

Here is the code I have now:

```
interface Updateable {
  update(string): void
};

const Edit = ({
  update
}: {
  update: string => void
}) => <a onClick={e => update(e.target.value)}>Something</a>

const UpdateContainer = ({ toRender }: { toRender: Updateable } ) => (
  <toRender update={message => alert(message)} />
)

const Wrapper = (
    <UpdateContainer toRender={Edit} />
);
```

This gives me the error:

> const UpdateContainer = ({ toRender }: { toRender: Updateable } ) => (
>
> `update` of Updateable. Property not found in 
>   `<UpdateContainer toRender={Edit} />`

How can I specify an interface based on react component properties? Or is there another thing besides an interface I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

[Playground](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDYFECMA20C8UDeAUFFAK4LIQBcUAFAG6IYlVQDOwATgJYB2A5gEoo2AHxQ6Aey7wCAXwDcBAgGMJPdlACi8LsGG1CxMkhRzqh0uRTV23fsLGTpcoaKgAeRFDUBhDF2UAa2w8HDFjChoIADpgRA4+CGBohiYIAVkRAGUJAFskgAtePncAekQRJVV1PQAxCQl9GgsAMwazfCIoNokbTmKHcSkZWVcxT28ePwDg0MGeqNj4xOTU5gzsvMLisoqqtQ04EwgfNTjeCA4mvChgCQAlCB54S6hZc1uHp5eOahowDgSMCsahHCjoLBjKCPRDKYAAEk0WHyPGAnh4IDEo0GNC67juj2erwiKBC+VYrEQiUGjEuwBo5MpiQyUFKlQE+xqUAA6hxEGBIBwAIxNLrEdxglCnVGIC5XAnfS4heoSWSs9mKFQHPS8-mCgBMouI4slJzOsp4rwVRI4IW0ujVbIIAnkQA)

```
type Updateable = {
  update: (value: string) => void
};

const Edit = ({
  update
}: Updateable ) => <a onClick={e => update(e.target.value)}>Something</a>

const Foo = ({
  foo
}: {
  foo: string => void
}) => <a onClick={e => foo(e.target.value)}>Something</a>

const UpdateContainer = ({ toRender }: { toRender: (props: Updateable) => React$Element<any> }) => (
  <toRender update={message => alert(message)} />
)

const Wrapper1 = (
    <UpdateContainer toRender={Foo} />
);

const Wrapper2 = (
    <UpdateContainer toRender={Edit} />
);
```

With this code, `Wrapper1` generates an error but `Wrapper2` doesn't. I switched the interface to a type as I'm not really familiar with interfaces in flowtype.

As for the problem, the problem is this part `{ toRender: Updateable }`.

`{ toRender: Updateable }` states toRender is something that implements Updateable, however that isn't the case when passing `Edit`.

`Edit` is a function that takes an argument `props`, and it's those props who implement `Updateable`.

I changed the code to be `{ toRender: (props: Updateable) => React$Element<any> }` to reflect this (and switched the interface to a type as previously mentioned, I'm not sure if that's needed, it's just way I know).

I hope this helps.